# Call function not all functions using argparse shortcuts

Tags: python, argparse

All I want is this.

```
a = first()
print("aaa updated")

b = second()
print("apt updated")

c = third()
print("fax updated")

import argparse parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("a", help="<description>", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("b", help="<description>", action="store_true") 
parser.add_argument("c", help="<description>", action="store_true") 
args = parser.parse_args()
```

To call either a or b or c using argparse. I don't want all of them called. I want to be able to run on CMD like `myscript.py -a` and that will call a.

Comment: You don't seem to have included argparse at all. Please give a [mre] to outline your implementation.

Comment: i just listed the functions, i didn't get far in using argparse but this is what i have so far.

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("a", help="<description>",
                    action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("b", help="<description>",
                    action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("c", help="<description>",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Comment: You seem to have no conditional logic there. Did you actually try anything? Maybe an `if`?

Comment: that's the part I'm struggling with. I try to do if args.a == True: print first()

Comment: And what's the *problem* with that? I'd suggest re-reading [mre], and maybe [ask] in general.

Comment: it's not calling the function a. that's the problem.

Comment: Why would it? As far as we can tell `a` *isn't* a function, unless `first()` returns a function. If you want to call `a`, maybe `if args.a: a()`?

Comment: Add `print(args)` statement, so you see what the `parser` is doing.  `args.a`, `args.b` etc gives access to the values.  Use those in your `if/then` logic.

Comment: duplicate/follow on to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820952/if-statements-that-will-call-different-functions-with-argparse

Answer (score 0):

sample script:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cmd', choices=['one','two','three'])
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.a: # is True
    print('A is True')

if args.cmd == 'one':
     print('do action one')
elif args.cmd == 'two':
     print('doing action two')
else:
     print('doing three')
```

sample runs:

```
1651:~/mypy$ python3 stack60822121.py -h
usage: stack60822121.py [-h] [--cmd {one,two,three}] [-a]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --cmd {one,two,three}
  -a
1651:~/mypy$ python3 stack60822121.py -a
Namespace(a=True, cmd=None)
A is True
doing three
1651:~/mypy$ python3 stack60822121.py --cmd one
Namespace(a=False, cmd='one')
do action one
```

`argparse` is just a way of parsing/decoding the user input.  It does not perform actions.  For that use ordinary Python logic.  That's your code.  At its most basic `argparse` set values to strings, boolean values, and numbers.  Use those.